# Jacoco report missing branches but tests are existing for those

Tags: java, jacoco

I have Spring Boot maven multimodule project with java version 21 and for code coverage using Jacoco version 0.8.11. Unit test are written using groovy.

I have class like this:

```
package ********************;

import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Getter
public enum SomeEnum {
    VALUE1("some-value1"),

    VALUE2("some-value2"),

    VALUE3("some-value3");

    private final String value;


    private SomeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static SomeEnum fromValue(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(someEnum -> someEnum.getValue().equals(value))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input value"));
    }
}
```

Here is Groovy test:

```
package *****************************

import *********************.SomeEnum
import spock.lang.Specification

class SomeEnumTest extends Specification {

    def 'test1'(String s, SomeEnum expected) {
        when:
        var resp = SomeEnum.fromValue(s)
        then:
        resp == expected
        where:
        s || expected
        'some-value1' || SomeEnum.VALUE1
        'some-value2' || SomeEnum.VALUE2
        'some-value3' || SomeEnum.VALUE3
    }

    def 'test2'() {
        when:
        SomeEnum.fromValue('bs')
        then:
        thrown(IllegalArgumentException)
    }
}
```

In the result of jacoco I see this part is not covered but the test for it exists. Constructor and enum values are covered. Test is successfully run. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This, unfortunately, is a known limitation of JaCoCo. JaCoCo works by injecting probes at various places into your code (in your example, before and after the `return`). If the JVM executes a probe, JaCoCo assumes any code before that probe has been covered. However, `return` or `throw` statements exit the function, and the probe right after the `return` or `throw` statement is never reached. JaCoCo therefore assumes that the `return`/`throw` have not been covered. JaCoCo's [FAQ](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html) have more info about that.

One peculiar thing about your example is though that JaCoCo usually recognizes this condition at least for `return` statements and therefore marks `return` statements as covered even if only the probe before the return statement is reached.

Comment: Note: It may also be a result of the issue discussed in [this pull request](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/321).